# Regular expression for the language containing neither aa nor bb

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

I want to create a regular expression for the language

$L=\{ w \in \{a,b\} |$ w has neither aa nor bb as a subword$\}$.

I've tried various things, but I can't seem to get the correct regular expression.

Comment: find the pattern a, ab, aba, abab, ababa, ababab, .abababa, ...

Comment: or $b, ba, bab, baba, \dots$. Kleene closure of something.

Comment: Would $((ab)^* \cup (ab)^* a) \cup ((ba)^* \cup(ba)^*b)$ work?

Comment: @Leonhard It seems you gave your own answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$((ab)^∗∪(ab)^∗a)∪((ba)^∗∪(ba)^∗b)$  will work.

The possibilities are: $a,ab,aba,ababa,...$ or $b,ba,bab,baba,...$ or empty string

Answer (score 0):

Empty or a singleton will work. Among the strings of at least two characters, $a$ and $b$ must alternate.

Hence $$b^+(ab)^*a^+$$

Answer (score -2):

(ab)*(a+ε)+(ba)*(b+ε) will work.